Is my papaya tree is hermaphrodite, male or female?
This papaya tree grew in a corner of our garden, probably from a seed of a papaya in our compost. I’ve learned that a papaya tree can be female or male or hermaphrodite. But I can’t tell if mine is of which gender. Can anyone help me identify this? Or is this too early to tell.


This is a female - the flowers are borne directly from the leaf axils, unlike males, which develop in clusters at the end of long stalks. Unless you have a male plant in close proximity to your female, you won't get any fruit.
